# Average Number of records per week day per Hour of Day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently i'm working on an app where i need to get average number of orders per week day per hour of the day and my code is like that

```
Spree::Order.group_by_day_of_week(:created_at, range: @start_date..@end_date, format: '%a').group_by_hour_of_day(:created_at, format: "%-l %P").count
```

I'm using [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem

But this just count results. how can i get the average ?!

Comment: Can you update question to include the code which defines the method `Spree::Order.group_by_hour_of_day` ?

Comment: I'm using GroupDate Gem

Comment: don't make me look that up, please at least post link to the gem in a comment...

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Did you use [explain](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-explain/) query to see what is happening?  Or see logs and get what AR is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The average of a set of numbers is simply the sum of the numbers divided by the total number of values in the set.

Assuming your method chain returns hash where the values are integers, then this should be as simple as:

```
hash = Spree::Order
         .group_by_day_of_week(:created_at, range: @start_date..@end_date, format: '%a')
         .count

average = hash.values.sum.to_f / hash.count.to_f
```

You may or maynot want to convert integers to floats, but you probably will.
If you end up with a number like:

```
 average == 0.15728715728715728
```

You might want to round it to say 2 decimals

```
avearge.round(2)
=>0.16
```

I don't think you really want to do this `.group_by_hour_of_day(:created_at, format: "%-l %P")` in the same chain, but probably a separate call chain for that, but I'm not sure.